# Reading config file with compile function in python

Tags: python

As given on https://prakhar.me/articles/the-compile-function/ , I am trying following code to read a config file using `compile` function of Python (I am working on Python version 3.5.3):

```
def config2dict(fname):
    d = {}
    codeobj = compile(open(fname).read(), 'myconfig', 'exec')
    exec(codeobj, d)
    return d

dd = config2dict("myconfig.cfg")
print(dd)
```

The myconfig.cfg file contains:

```
DB_HOST = 172.123.125.34
DB_USER = app_user
DB_PASS = lly4paw
```

However, I am getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mytest.py", line 19, in <module>
    dd = config2dict("myconfig.cfg")
  File "mytest.py", line 14, in config2dict
    codeobj = compile(open(fname).read(), 'myconfig', 'exec')
  File "myconfig", line 1
    DB_HOST = 172.123.125.34
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Comment: Okay, after taking a closer look at your question, it appears you're missing quotes around your strings. `DB_HOST = 172.123.125.34` should be `DB_HOST = "172.123.125.34"` or else, the parser throws an error.

Comment: I have to keep all values in quotes. But now the returned dictionary contains large amount of data - seems like whole environment is being added to it.

Comment: I see there is an extra key,  `__builtins__`, added to the dictionary when I try your code. You could try `d.pop('__builtins__', None)` before returning from `config2dict` to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

the d dict should be set in the compiled code,and, the data should be splitted to set the dict.

```
def config2dict(fname):
    d = {}
    codeobj = compile("txt=open(fname).read()\nd.update(dict([tuple([y.strip() for y in x.split(\"=\")]) for x in txt.split(\"\\n\") if x!=\"\"]))", 'myconfig', 'exec')
    exec(codeobj)
    return d

dd = config2dict("myconfig.cfg")
print(dd)
```

Comment: sure, I double checked, it works on my computer, win7.  when you copy the code out, be careful about the spaces. if you have an error, what is the error? I ran with "python compiletest.py", compiletest.py's content is the code pasted previously.

Comment: You have altered your answer now.

Comment: I added strip() before tupling the parameter pair, because the data contains spaces around '=', just to make it better.

Comment: With this code I am getting an empty dictionary: `{}` . I have just copied and ran your code with same cfg file as mentioned in the question.

Comment: How could it be? I copied the myconfig.cfg, so , the content should be the same. And, I tried on linux and windows, both works, the output is a dict with data from myconfig.cfg. if d is still empty, it seems the codeobj is not executed, did u try to clean the compiled files?

Comment: I did not delete any pyc files or tried in any other way to clean compiled files. Could version be an issue?

Comment: should not be, still, I am using 2.7.14

Comment: I am using Python version 3.5.3 on Debian Stable Linux. I installed Python from Debian repository.

Comment: found the root cause, in python 2, the compiled block can use outside variables, but in python3, it seems the outside block of the compiled code  keeps the original address of the dict variable, so, if use equals, the original dict was not changed, so if we use update, it can change the dict, and the result is correct.